# Glimpse.axd 403ing On IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, http-status-code-403, glimpse, httpforbiddenhandler

When trying to access /Glimpse.axd after I've published to IIS (7.5), I'm now receiving a 403 Forbidden response.  Is there a setting in IIS that disables access to .axd files?  Or is this something else entirely?

Answer (score 12):

This is usually due to the fact that your source IP Address is not allowed in the web.config section for Glimpse. I just ran in to this issue yesterday.

Look for this in your web.config file, it can go anywhere in the web.config file.

```
<glimpse enabled="true">
  <ipAddresses>
    <!-- List of IP addresses allowed to get Glimpse data. Optional. localhost (IPv4  &IPv6) by default -->
    <add address="x.x.x.x"/> <!--The ip of your machine -->
    <add address="::1"/>
  </ipAddresses>
</glimpse>
```

Comment: nice to see no response on this. :) Offensive :)

Comment: This worked for me. I was surprised because I didn't even have these additional settings, so I figured why bother. But adding them did the trick.

Comment: This seems like an onerous task for a project with many developers... is there a better way than to have everyone supply their ip in web.config, or am I missing something?

Comment: This hasn't helped for mine, I've added the ip address in, but I'm still getting a 403 :(

Comment: Can you fix the formatting? I tried but my edit was auto-rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I got an error like this when trying to access `http://leniel-pc:8083/glimpse.axd`:

> 403 Forbidden 
>   Ensure **'aa90::edad:55a5:7777:cd2c%11'** is configured for
>   Glimpse access.

After doing this:

```
<glimpse enabled="true">
  <ipAddresses>
    <!-- List of IP addresses allowed to get Glimpse data. -->
    <!--The ip of your machine -->
    <add address="aa90::edad:55a5:7777:cd2c%11"/>
  </ipAddresses>
</glimpse>
```

Problem solved! :D