# Http 403 when using Glimpse on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I am trying to use Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com). It works fine in Visual Studio on my development machine in both Cassini and IIS 7.5

On the server (actually 2 servers behind NLB) I get back a http 403 and nothing more.

I googled and found this answer: [Glimpse.axd 403ing On IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843560/glimpse-axd-403ing-on-iis)
However no luck for me. I setup the IpAddress of my machine in the web.config as suggested - tried both Ipv4 and Ipv6. But no luck.

I also tried setting the

ipForwardingEnabled="true"

Since it is suggested to use that when running against a set of servers behind NLB.

During my fiddling with settings I learned that the Glimpse code does seem to be loaded and run e.g. I tried to change an IpAddress to something invalid and this was not accepted.

So my guess is that the Http 403 is because of something Glimpse cannot access e.g. the File System or something.

Probably something in our server setup.

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions ?

BTW: The website is ASP.NET - not MVC it is using SSL but I got the same error on another site using http

Regards Jesper

Answer (score 0):

Jesper,

It's a bit difficult to tell whats going wrong based on the information in your question.

I'd recommend turning on logging in Glimpse by changing your config to the following:

```
<glimpse enabled="true" loggingEnabled="true">
```

From there you will get a log file that provides information about the internals of Glimpse that should help you track down the problem.